# Isolate leading string before one of two delimiting characters

Tags: php, substring

How can I get the substring before the first space or dot?

Like

```
$string = "test.test"
//result = test

$string = "test doe"
//result = test
```

Sure I can use explode two times, but I am sure that's not the best solutions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to split on several different chars, take a look at [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split)

```
//split string on space or period:
$split=preg_split('/[ \.]/', $string);
```

Comment: This answer provides an array, but the asker seeks a string.

Comment: The pattern could be simplified to `/[ .]/` or `/ |\./`.

Answer (score 2):

There's string token [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php).

Comment: This "hint" should have been a comment under the question, because it does very little to express how the function call should be implemented to resolve the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You want the **[`strtok`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)** function. The manual gives this example:

```
<?php
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";
/* Use tab and newline as tokenizing characters as well  */
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
?>
```

Though in your case I suspect that using `explode` twice is easier and looks better.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the sample data and is not designed for the asker's task.

Comment: @mickmackusa, before you edited the question, it asked for _any nice way to split an string after `" "` or `"."`_. That is what `strtok` does, though it's not very clear what the author of the question really wanted.

Comment: I did not alter the [mcve]. The sample input and exact desired result has been 100% clear since the question was first posted.  There is absolutely no reason to be mentioning `\t` or `\n`.  This code copied from the manual is not generous or tailored to the asked question.  So many 2009 answers on Stack Overflow are low-quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok()` and offer the two characters as its character mask parameter:

```
foreach (array("test.test", "test doe") as $string) {
    echo strtok($string, " ."), " \n";
}
// test
// test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a strtr of . into space and then explode by space. Since strtr is very fast.

Comment: Translating then exploding is needless extra work.