# How can I avoid separating the search query to search a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, search, cakephp

When a user tries to search for people on our system, we've noticed that they often type a full name for their search.
How can we enable full name searching on our database when first name and last name are stored in different columns?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to store f/l name together?  If you're worried about breaking other parts of your app, you could do some beforeFilter magic to split things up.  OR, you could just create a new column that is f + L names concatenated.  This violates 3rd normal form, but is a reasonable hack if you have performance concerns about using concat as shown by dbemerlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working but neither fast nor reliable solution would be:

```
SELECT foo
FROM   bar
WHERE  CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = $search_name
```

(Not sure about MySQL CONCAT syntax atm, you might need to concat twice)

There is a high chance that this won't use any indexes, slowing down the search a lot.

A better solution would be to just split the name:

```
$names = explode(' ', $search_name);

SELECT foo
FROM   bar
WHERE  firstname = $names[0]
AND    lastname  = $names[1]
```

Even better:
Provide two input boxes and label them first and lastname so users will enter the search correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Even better - If you are using CakePHP 1.3 then simply create a 'full_name' virtual field. Do your query against that field.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1609/Creating-virtual-fields
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1610/Using-virtual-fields

```
class User extends AppModel {
    ...
    var $virtualFields = array(
        'full_name' => 'CONCAT( User.first_name, " ", User.last_name )'
    );
    ...
}
```

Since Cake treats virtual fields as regular fields for the primary model you can simply do a find like so.

```
$User->find( 'all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.full_name' => $search_name
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

You could even throw in some MySQL LIKE goodness in the conditions

```
$User->find( 'all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.full_name LIKE' => '%' . $search_name . '%',
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

This syntax means the end-user can put part of the first, part of the last or the whole name into the search field and still get results without worrying about if the code is doing finds on first, last or both.

Answer (score 0):

Your 99% case is probably going to be this:

1. Split the string on the *first* whitespace
2. Assume the first part is the first name, and the 2nd part is the last name

Depending on the number of users in your system, and the... "creativeness" of their names, you may get a few false negatives from this approach.

You could also consider providing separate fields to the user.

Comment: And if false negatives are a problem (i.e., you want users with creative names to be able to search, even if it means having a few extra results for everyone else) you could do a last-name-only search.  Maybe have some logic in there so it'll pare it down if there are too many results (like for Jones or something).

Answer (score 0):

How do you search the people in your DB?

If you have a SQL query you can do it somehow like that:

1. Separate the search text into parameters. so you have firstname and lastname in 2 separate parameters. ([Stackoverflow: How to split a string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063087/how-to-split-a-string-with-php))
2. then you can use the different parameters to build a query that fits your needs:

   ```
   select * 
   from People
   where 
      (firstname LIKE param1 AND lastname LIKE param2) OR
      (firstname LIKE param2 AND lastname LIKE param1) OR ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a single fulltext index on first_name and last_name. Then, just include a test for MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ($query). Or if you have more than just that field to search against, add those to the index as well.

Let SQL do the work for you.